# LibreOffice won't show Hebrew characters

Tags: libreoffice, hebrew

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and Libre Office 3.5

I tried upgrading to  Libre Office 4 using the ppa but failed and decided to go back using purge.
After the comeback the hebrew stopped working, though english still works.
Now I can't write any Hebrew letters in either  Libre Office application and can't paste Hebrew text - it just stays blank.

The language settings are set up well with the CTL - it shows Hebrew - and the Hebrew default fonts are set for Arial.

Where is the problem?